# "Test Login Needed" App review in Google Play

Tags: google-play

I recently uploaded a new app in the google play console to review, then I was receive an email that say:

> Please provide login credentials to the support team before you submit
> any updated version for another review (select “Test Login Needed” and
> include the test login account and password details in the open box
> field).

I can't find the “Test Login Needed” to select it.

Can anybody tell where this option is?

Comment: Google Play should provide more details of where this is found, that one must redo 'target audience and content' to be able to provide test login account and password

Answer (score 239, accepted):

Updated 09/2020:

**New Play Console:**

1. Sign in to your [Play Console](https://play.google.com/console)
2. On the left menu, scroll all the way down and select "App content"
3. Select the "Actioned" tab
4. Select "App access" > "Manage"
5. Select "All or some functionality is restricted" and enter your login credentials and save

**Old Play Console:**

1. Sign in to your [Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish)
2. On the left menu, go to "Store Presence" -> "App Content"
3. Select "App Access" -> "All or some of functionality is restricted"
4. Enter login credentials and save

Comment: This is not a bit better in the new "improved" console. Those instructions for testers should have a prominent place in relation to the tracks. Apple solved that much better (while their store submission UX is still awful in general).

Comment: The "App Content" is listed under the "Policy" section down below.

Comment: In general I find Google's play console to be much more cluttered and confusing than Apple. They're also often slower to review now. Great progress :(

Comment: I'm stuck with this situation. My app sign-in flow with Google Sign In (server side token verification). Should I have to submit google account and password? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69172752/how-to-submit-playstore-app-access-credentials-for-google-sign-in-authentication

Comment: @Akashkhan When I did that I created a test account and just handed the credentials to Google (and Apple if releasing on iOS)

Comment: I have done this and its been 1 week still no google answer, should I contact their support?

Comment: @Liso what does the status of your app say? If it's your first app it can take a while for it to get approved. Nothing wrong with reaching out to their support though

Comment: We have done this and we still see this message: "Your app will soon be removed for not adhering to Google Play Developer Programme Policies. Fix violations as soon as possible."

We have reached out to google support but the answer is that policy issues can only be solved through the play console.... :-/

Comment: @chris08002 how did you get it resolved? i have the same situation, although they replied in some instances the warning may continue to show, what does that mean?!

Comment: Wow, can't believe I had to come to stack overflow to tell me how to find something in a Google UI... Thanks!

Answer (score 42):

1. Sign in to your [Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/).
2. Navigate to "Store Presence" > "App Content"
3. Start the "Target audience and content" questionnaire, or select "Start Again" if you already submitted.
4. In step 2 "App Details" choose "All or some functionality is restricted" under "Instructions for app access".
5. Enter the test login credentials there for app review team to access.

Comment: The weird thing about this is that you can only get to step 2 if you say that your app targets children...so if you have an app that isn't targeting children (in my case, a business productivity app), you have to include children in your targeting in order to provide the Google Play reviewer with test login credentials. Very odd...

Comment: this is really confusing!!

Comment: you should navigate to Policy > App content. and then click on the Manage button on the App access section.

Comment: If the app is for a financial institution and creating a test account is complex, e.g Some business documents are required. Can an app in a test track be used? How does one proceed?

Comment: I'm stuck with this situation. My app sign-in flow with Google Sign In (server side token verification). Should I have to submit google account and password? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69172752/how-to-submit-playstore-app-access-credentials-for-google-sign-in-authentication

Answer (score 42):

My console was different [@Prasad DE Zoysa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588742/prasad-de-zoysa)

Here's an update.

1. Sign in to your Play Console.
2. Navigate to "App Content" (Under policy section)
3. Navigate to "App access" questionnaire - you might find it under the "Actioned" tab - and click manage.
4. Choose "All or some functionality is restricted" under "Instructions for app access".

Enter the test login credentials there for app review team to access.

Edited in Sept. 2023

Answer (score 38):

Please follow these instruction if it's helpful
1st instruction
[image: 1st instruction]

2nd instruction
[image: 2nd instruction]

3rd instruction
[image: 3rd instruction]

Then save

Also do this
[image]

Comment: My app is still rejected with same reason please help me how can i resolve it

Comment: Can you please provide me the error  ss or something!!

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find it

Comment: @RaselKhan My app still has the same error after providing test credentials, please help to solve it

Comment: @RajiAC I just update my answer please follow now. May be it could be helpful for you

Comment: @RaselKhan thank you very much, the warning got cleared after the deadline only even though i had resolved it 2 weeks ago