# Test Login needed in app review on Google

Tags: authentication, google-play

We are trying to submit our app by about two weeks, and we always get the same response:

"**Test Login Needed** -
In order to review your app for “Designed for Families” eligibility, we will need you to provide a test login account. Please provide login credentials to the support team before you submit any updated version for another review (select “Test Login Needed” and include the test login account and password details in the open box field)."

In our searches we find two ways of doing this:

1 - Store Presence > App content > Start Again > Next > All or some functionalities are restricted > Provide the email or phone and password

2 - Release management > Pre-launch report > Settings > Provide the email and password

We tried the both ways

What else are we supposed to do?

Comment: This link might be what you're looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56660196/test-login-needed-app-review-in-google-play

Comment: well, as i said, we already tried this

Answer (score 1):

Well, apparently it was a mistake by the review team, We send a email to the support and they replied "We’ve accepted your appeal" and just asked us to just resubmit our app with no changes.

Comment: This is so unprofessional of Google