# Google policy for uploading app about Instructions for app access

Tags: google-play

In Play Store when publish a new it ask below

If parts of your app are restricted based on login credentials, memberships, location or other forms of authentication, provide details so that Google can review your app

-All functionality is available without special access

-All or some functionality is restricted

My app is basically education based and it requires login for each user. Is it necessary to share the credential with google OR i choose All functionality is available without special access

Answer (score 0):

If it's authenticated content, then according to and insinuated by [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56931306/638153), you should create a test account for your Google Reviewer to use in the reviewing of your app.

`5. Enter the test login credentials there for app review team to access.`