# App access in new update of Google Play Console

Tags: google-play-console

My app is having login for admin users and login for other users. And mandatory login for all users to view cart. What should I do?

Please Check this Screenshots:

- [Screenshot in Play Console App access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKZp1.png)
- [Screenshot for add new instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkeLt.png)

Comment: What did you end up doing? I'm currently searching to see if they are asking for a back door (faux/testing) account.

Comment: Further research revealed a test account should be created for the Google Reviewer to use in the reviewing of your app. Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56931306/638153): `5. Enter the test login credentials there for app review team to access.`