# How to submit PlayStore app access credentials for google sign in authentication

Tags: android, google-play, googlesigninaccount

I have an app where a user needs to log in with a google account & purchase premium (play billing) for accessing premium features. Everything works perfectly.

Recently playstore force developers to submit app credentials to test if the app has certain functions which require authentication.

[image]

If my app has a normal email and password for auth then I'll submit to google play a test user's e-mail and password from my backend server. But now It's Google Sign in. I don't know any test google account which uses app reviewers. The [doc](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859455?visit_id=637671972568597126-3350551876&rd=1#app_access) has no information about that.

In this situation, should I have to submit my personal google account and password to review app authentication (because it was added to the test licence in the GooglePlay developer console)?

or there is some test google email account from (playstore app reviewer) for whitelisting on my server-side?

Comment: Did you tried the proposed answer?

Comment: good.

Step:
play console -> Policy -> App content -> App access -> Manage -> All or some functionality is restricted -> add tester account

Answer (score 5):

You Just need to tell them to "login using Google Account" in "**Any other instruction**" field, as shown below, you don't have to create a test account for this. I tried this many times before.

[image: here]

Comment: is it worked for you?

Comment: This is not working. Do you have proof that this has worked for you?

Comment: It is working for me, this is a screen shot from a released app of mine. Anyway if it does not work with you, create a test Google account just for this case.

Answer (score 3):

So I was stuck on this issue for about a whole month, I couldn't update my production app.

[Google documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842757?hl=en&visit_id=637671972568597126-3350551876&rd=1#credentials) clearly state that `Note that you do not need to provide credentials if your app supports "Sign-in with Google,” which enables the crawler to log in automatically.` However this was not the case for me.

I tried:

1. Going with the 1st option that - No special access is required. - Never worked
2. 2nd option - Stating the the app requires Google login (didn't submit any credentials). - Never worked

**Eventually, what worked was** - I created another email account on my mobile device. Then submitted the credentials to Google.

**Point to note** - ensure the email account you create doesn't contain any 2 factor authentication or verification as this won't work.

Comment: Hello, in my case my application have google authentication but mails end with only  some x domain. How can i add app access to this kind of case ?

Comment: @Phanindra, I don't understand, do you mean you also have log in with email

Comment: no my application contains  have google authentication but allows  only my company emails. How can i add those credentials ?

Comment: Since you can't share the company email, you should follow the same procedure of creating a test account, if that fails then as the last resort you just have to share the company email then later after approval you should change the password

Comment: My app only allows Google & GitHub auth, no email-password auth, how should I go about it?

Comment: @PedroMassango since it contains Google you can simply do as I suggested in the solution but at times the bot/crawler may opt to go with the Github auth, if possible create a test account for it as well and submit for review

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that you do not need to do this in the case of a Google account.

If you see the pre-launch reports in the Google Play console, and watch the replay of the test, you will see that when the Google Play robot encounters the Google Account login screen, they will have an account with a `@cloudtestlabaccounts.com` email that they will use to login as seen on the below image:

[image]

As you can see, Google Play robots have Google accounts available to them to login and therefore you do not need to put as special access, unless if you are using non-Google accounts to login.

I personally use Google Accounts as login and never submitted any login information and they didn't have any issue with this.

Comment: Good observation, however I also tried submitting that "No special access is required" and the update still got rejected.

Comment: As mentioned in the docs - https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842757?hl=en&visit_id=637671972568597126-3350551876&rd=1#credentials

Answer (score 0):

I created a Google account specifically for app testing purposes. I use it for both Android and iOS. You submit the credentials for that account for review. After your app is approved, you can always change the password and just update the credentials when you submit the app for review again.

Comment: How to fix login attempt blocked while play console team trying to review our app?

Answer (score 0):

I tried submitting `use "google login"`  in `any other instructions` field but it didn't work.
What worked was I created a demo google account and submitted the email and password. Also, wrote `use "google login"`  in `any other instructions`.
hope it helps