# How to submit PlayStore app access credentials for google sign in authentication (rejected multiple times)?

Tags: android, google-play, google-signin

I have an app where a user needs to sign in with a google account for initial authentication, and if they are a new user they require to key in a localized (Malaysia) phone number to get an SMS OTP, and thereafter fill in the profile with user particulars.

The app was rejected (previously there was no rejection to the submission of the app) when they used their own test account and reached the OTP page and did not fill in any particulars.

Then I resubmit for review with a test account with the OTP page solved from the backend.

After resubmitting for review, the reviewer was stuck on the registration page. Which I then amended accordingly by giving a working test account that has already completed the OTP and registration page.

But now, the app is still being rejected multiple times even giving different configurations or explanations, with a vague message (below) and screenshot showing the landing screen (the reviewer is no longer attempting to test the account).

[image: Rejected google store]

The rejection explanation gives no clarity on how I can fix this. Any ideas?

[How to submit PlayStore app access credentials for google sign in authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69172752/how-to-submit-playstore-app-access-credentials-for-google-sign-in-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did this using the following way:

1. Create a test account using test phone number
2. From your backend make the test phone number always accepts a static OTP (for example: 1234)
3. these information in Google Play Console and it will work