# "Test Login Needed" for Google Sign In

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I have not yet published my app on play store, but from what I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56660196/test-login-needed-app-review-in-google-play) I understand that I need to provide login credentials for my app for google to test my app, But I am still trying to figure out what is the case for apps that only require Google Sign In, Am I to give away my google account email and password to the team to login from my account and test the app? or what?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a test account (not your main account) and upload the credentials according to the instructions in this answer of the question you referenced: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69434135/3417617