# "Need login credentials for app review" for an app which only has mobile number as Login option

Tags: android, firebase

I pushed an app on the google play store and the app was rejected with the following issue.

> Issue: Need login credentials for app review

My app uses the only mobile number as a login option and we are using Firebase messaging services to send OTP messages.

Google in their email also stated that:

> If your app normally uses 2-Step Verification (e.g. SMS verification), biometrics (e.g. a fingerprint or face scan) or a location-dependent password (e.g. geo-gate), please provide valid demo credentials that we can use instead.

I am wondering how to provide a valid mobile number and OTP for them to validate this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Test Login Needed" App review in Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56660196/test-login-needed-app-review-in-google-play)

Comment: this does not answer... My question is different. IN real world, people have real mobile numbers and OTP come to their numbers. While we dont have a test number.
On top of that, we are using Firebase OTP verification service which means that OTP authentication happens with firebase. Does Firebase provide any test numbers?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, Ahmed. However, I found a method that really overrides any such process.

1. Go to the firebase console and select your project
2. Then go to Authentication -> Sign-in Method
3. Click on Edit configuration on Phone
4. Expand "Phone Numbers for testing (optional)"
5. Add Phone numbers and Verification codes.

That's it, now just add this information on the Play console and you shall be good.

Answer (score 1):

I would image two scenarios

1. Make a mobile for testing, with a fixed password, you can later remove it from the production database, after the app is published
2. You provide a URL that specifically exposes the OTP.

   1. Your define a test mobile as `0123456789`
   2. When the OTP is sent, it is also saved somewhere in the backend
   3. A URL you send to the Play store exposes this password
   4. You later delete this page and test mobile, afer the app is published